# WSO2 Identity Server - code for commonauth and samlsso webapps

Tags: wso2, endpoint, wso2-identity-server

I need to customize commonauth and samlsso endpoints to pass-through some query parameters that I'd like to make it back to my service provider for a number of use cases.  Which Carbon or IS projects hold code for each of these webapps?

- /commonauth
- /samlsso

I did some searching but I'm uncertain that I'm looking at the right stuff, so help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find source code for Commonauth from [1] and samlsso from [2]. The source code is for IS 5.1.0

[1]https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/tree/master/components/authentication-framework
[2]https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/tree/master/components/sso-saml

Thanks

Comment: Do you know where could find the latest patch code for org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint that is intended for IS 5.0.0?

Comment: The latest code contains all the patches in IS 5.0.0 and the source code of all the patches provided by wso2 is available in git hub.

Comment: Any particular url?  We've had a difficult time nailing it down.  Anything we've found, the debugger was a few lines off when connected.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is, the latest code is great, but I need to make sure I'm point-in-time compatible, hence the need for revisions or branch names.  I'm not going to be using 5.1 anytime soon, so 5.0.0 completely matters.  5.1's most up-to-date stuff has too much to back-port...not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

For Identity Server 5.0.0 these sources are located in SVN at the following locations:

- https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk11/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint/
- https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk11/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml/